# applicability of various biblical laws to today

Tags: old-testament, law

So I was looking at http://www.buzzfeed.com/omgitsanf/19-things-the-bible-forbids-other-than-homosexuali-b83k and wondered what it's applicability is to today.

Like if those were laws that some Roman parish had that doesn't necessarily mean that those laws have been endorsed by God.

And even if they were endorsed by God, how serious is a violation of them? Violating the ten commandments is a pretty serious offense but violating the laws spelled out in the Book of Leviticus or the Book of Deuteronomy or whatever...  doesn't seem like it'd be as severe, comparatively.

Comment: It is a pretty serious mistake to see them as laws as they are blessings. If you get to understand that you will see that you do not need to ask the question.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Please summarise the article you linked to and then clearly explain what you don't understand.

Comment: The two above are just two of quite a few that are very, very similar to your question. This topic, what laws apply when, is very big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no degree of sin, any sin carries the same penalty; which is death!

Sin is disobedience of God, The sin that Adam and Eve committed in  the Garden of Eden was in doing what God had forbid them to do and he even gave them the penalty for disobeying him.

All Scripture is quoted from the English Standard Version unless otherwise noted.

> Genesis 2:16 and 17  And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, "You may surely eat of every tree of the garden, **but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die."**

The penalty was for disobeying God not for having the knowledge of good and evil, after all when Jesus walked upon the Earth he had the knowledge of good and evil, otherwise how would he be able to call the Pharisees hypocrites.

Now that you have the bad news here is the Good News!

Jesus fulfilled the law.

> Matthew 5:17 and 18  "Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them. For truly, I say to you, until heaven and earth pass away, not an iota, not a dot, will pass from the Law until all is accomplished.

But that fulfillment has a few conditions attached to it:

> Mat 5:19 and 20  Therefore whoever relaxes one of the least of these commandments and teaches others to do the same will be called least in the kingdom of heaven, but whoever does them and teaches them will be called great in the kingdom of heaven. For I tell you, unless your righteousness exceeds that of the scribes and Pharisees, you will never enter the kingdom of heaven.

However that only applies to those who are eligible to be in Heaven. Or in other words Christians. God will forgive our sins and we can become eligible to enter the Kingdom of Heaven, but that again has some conditions attached to it:

> John 14:1 through 6 KJV Let not your heart be troubled: ye believe in God, believe also in me. In my Father's house are many mansions: if it were not so, I would have told you. I go to prepare a place for you. And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come again, and receive you unto myself; that where I am, there ye may be also. And whither I go ye know, and the way ye know. Thomas saith unto him, Lord, we know not whither thou goest; and how can we know the way? Jesus saith unto him, ***I am the way, the truth, and the life: no man cometh unto the Father, but by me.***

So if we are to go to Heaven there is only one way, and that is through Jesus Christ. But then again that is not just believing that Jesus existed it is more than that. in that you must believe that his death and resurrection paid your sin debt in full.

So now that we have escaped the penalty of death does that mean we are free to just sin all we want with no consequences? **Not by along shot**!

First of all think back to Matthew 5:19 and 20, where he says *anyone who relaxes one of the least of these commandments*, That means we are still bound by those commandments, and remember that they are all the same in God's eyes, and so we cannot intentionally break any of those commandments and if your child learns from you that they can get by with doing that, God will frown on you.

When we sin whether intentionally or unintentionally those are our sins and if Jesus death and resurrection is going to pay for them then we have to give them to him. So after we qualify to enter Heaven what about those sins we commit after that. Those sins also have to be given to Christ and we must ask God to forgive them just the same as we did when we first gave our past sins to Jesus and asked God to forgive us based on Jesus sacrifice, and until you do that through prayer and confession they are still your sins, and will not be covered by Jesus death and resurrection.

Any law that God endorsed would be already contained in the laws enumerated in the Bible. Any law not based on Scripture is not a law, as far as God is concerned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `There is no degree of sin` -- This isn't exactly true (at least not according to most Christians).  See [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/2198/20).

Comment: @Flimzy That depends on how you read those verses quote in the post. I'll explain what I mean by that, but it will be very brief. Matthew 12:31-32 is about forgiveness of sin and says that one sin is unforgivable. 1st Corinthians 6:18 is about who the sin is against, Sexual sins are not only against God but one is defaming themselves. Matthew 7:3 is about how much we sin or whether or not we are able to accept that we are as much or more guilty of sin as those we despise.  of

Comment: I agree that *it depends*... but that means that an answer needs to provide a doctrinal framework, rather than making a "truth statement."

Comment: @Flimzy As far as John 19:11 The way I read that is that you must remember who Jesus was talking to; that being the Sanhedrin. The like most Christians today held that there were varying degrees of sin. As an example let me give you this one. When a wife asks does this make me look fat? The husband will say no even though he believes it does. How many of us consider that to be as great a sin as Judas betrayal of Jesus, and yet as far as God is concerned they are both worthy of death or more specifically the second death or eternal life in the lake of fire.

Comment: @Flimzy Doctrinal framework means nothing more than a specific group agrees on a particular interpretation of Scripture. My retort to that is why is their idea more correct than mine. That is the reason why Jesus is the Judge and not the majority opinion of mankind. Jesus judgment is true, ours is not. I do not claim that my interpretation is correct that is why I use Biblical passages as answers to questions, I can be wrong but Scriptures cannot.

Comment: But "doctrinal framework" is the standard by which our community has agreed to abide. Everyone has an opinion, but we require that answers here correspond to a doctrinal framework to limit the number of opinion answers we get.

Comment: @Flimzy As far as I know my answers are in keeping with Southern Baptist Doctrine which States that "we believe that the Holy Bible is the inerrant word of God".,

Comment: Your answer(s) should probably say that then... "According to Southern Baptist doctrine...". And bonus points for referencing an official SB confession of faith (or similar document) which confirms the view is held by them.

Comment: @Flimzy I could do that, but many who disagree with the Southern Baptists would dismiss my answers on that grounds alone, that is why I prefer to quote the King James translation since most Protestant faiths honor it.

Comment: Well, without that, you're expressing your personal opinion which is expressly disallowed here. If you want your answers to be accepted according to our community guidelines, it's not a recommendation--it is *essential* that you reference a doctrinal framework.

Comment: @Flimzy OK will do.

Comment: In this particular case it doesn't matter much, since the question is closed, and will probably be automatically deleted by the system in a couple of weeks. But moving forward, it would be benefit you to understand better how this site works.

Comment: And note that my comments are in no way meant to express disagreement with your opinion... :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I agree with Bye that Sin is sin and there's not varying degrees of it.
 Yet when I looked at that post you linked it's talking more about Old Testament laws out of context and disregarding What the New Testament has to say about those very same laws

Point in case most of the items this article talks about what kinds of foods we can't eat because they are unclean yet those passages are superseded by Book in the New Testament
Quoting Acts 10 12-15 from the NIV version:

> 12 It contained all kinds of four-footed animals, as well as reptiles and birds. 13 Then a voice told him, “Get up, Peter. Kill and eat.”
>   14 “Surely not, Lord!” Peter replied. “I have never eaten anything impure or unclean.”
>   15 The voice spoke to him a second time, “Do not call anything impure that God has made clean.”

So While Sin is still sin and should be avoided, do be careful that the Rules you are following are the ones that God is still expecting you to follow.